# WSDLException : An error occurred trying to call web services

Tags: java, eclipse, wsdl

I'm trying to generate a proxy class from a dynamic `WSDL` file with Eclipse. And I get an error due to an imported schema the `WSDL` .
Please help me resolve this trouble.

I get the following exception:

```
Error javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'http://172.22.4.12/PKISignWS.asmx'.: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The element type "p" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</p>"
```

But I haven't `p` in my `WSDL`.

Answer (score 0):

`.asmx` is usually the suffix used for ASP.NET web services and their `WSDL` is accessed by adding `?wsdl` to the `.asmx` service address.

So you should be using `http://172.22.4.12/PKISignWS.asmx?wsdl` as the target for the `WSDL` file.